# Accepted Answer Transference

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

I offered the accepted answer to another person's question here:

[How to change the color of my navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188926/how-to-change-the-color-of-my-navigation/12188938#12188938)

But another person answered it better than I did and offered more detail.

I think it would be nice if I could somehow point out (within the system) that I think someone else answered it better. Maybe I could keep some of the reputation bonus and the person with the better answer keeps the rest (maybe 3/7 split, in favor of the better answer, or maybe a separate Humbly-Accepts-Defeat score :P ).

Would be really nice if it were presented to visitors to the site that I 'passed the buck' to the better answer.

Please note, I am *NOT* talking about overriding the accepted answer.

To know that someone is credible enough to give away rep points in favor of selecting the better answer seems useful to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like an unnecessarily complicated addition to the rep system to me:

If you feel the other user got slighted, you have several methods of recourse:

1. Comment that you think they have the better answer.
2. Offer a +50 bounty for the better answer.
3. Upvote their answer (which gives them a full 10 rep)

In the case of the third option, you can tell the good users who do this frequently by their "Sportsmanship" badges.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Best that can be done is:

Write a comment on your answer, or edit your answer.
Upvote the answer that you like best.

Comment: I did not ask the question I referenced. I'm saying if I answer a question and my answer is accepted, but I think that someone else did a better job, I should have a way as the original accepted answerer to let the system know that someone else did better.

Comment: you'll have to let the other person know via comment, but in the end, is up to them. it's their question.

Comment: I'm not saying override their Acceptance of the answer, I'm saying indicate that as the person who wrote the accepted answer, I think someone else did better.

Comment: still think the best way is via comment or editing your answer

Comment: Could you possibly re-read the question?  I think you've misunderstood what the OP is getting at here.